# Passing regex pattern as an system argument to Python script

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a Python script which accepts a regex pattern, and it does something like this:

```
import sys
import re

pattern = re.compile(sys.argv[1])
time_string = '2017-08-14 11:07:46'

def func(pattern):
    if re.search(pattern, time_string):
        # do something
```

But when I run `python script.py \d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` the condition in the function always ends up false. I'm stuck with this problem for days and I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `'\'` characters, they are special to bash:

```
python script.py \\d{4}\-\\d{2}\-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}
```

Or as comment suggests, put the whole string in single quote, then `'\'` will be treated literally:

```
python script.py '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
```

Comment: Alternatively, just `python script.py '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'`.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov Good point, updated.